filter a list of variables in a single column in R
I am working with the below data frame:
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

item_no<-c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6)
exp_date<-c("06/27/2024","07/30/2024",
            "06/27/2024","07/30/2024",
            "06/27/2024","07/30/2024",
            "06/27/2024","07/30/2024",
            "08/27/2024","09/30/2024",
            "10/27/2024","10/30/2024")
price_data<-c(10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,60,60,60,60)

example_df<-data.frame(item_no,exp_date,price_data)

print(example_df)

  item_no   exp_date price_data
1        1 06/27/2024         10
2        1 07/30/2024         15
3        2 06/27/2024         20
4        2 07/30/2024         25
5        3 06/27/2024         30
6        3 07/30/2024         35
7        4 06/27/2024         40
8        4 07/30/2024         45
9        5 08/27/2024         60
10       5 09/30/2024         60
11       6 10/27/2024         60
12       6 10/30/2024         60

#to check number of different expiry dates
length(unique(example_df$exp_date))

which should give me 6 different unique expiry dates
#to see what are the different expiry dates
example_df%>%
  group_by(exp_date)%>%
  summarise(n())

 exp_date   `n()`
  <chr>      <int>
1 06/27/2024     4
2 07/30/2024     4
3 08/27/2024     1
4 09/30/2024     1
5 10/27/2024     1
6 10/30/2024     1


#filter out the selected item from the dataset and display exp_data and price_data
example_df<-example_df%>% 
  filter(item_no==1)%>%
  select(exp_date,price_data)

Here I would like to ask:

The last part of code gives me the filtered result based on one single variable in a particular column, say if I would like to filter more than 1  variable, say item_no==1 &2, how should I go about it? All ideas are appreciated. Thanks.


You can use either item_no %in% 1:2 or item_no == 1 | item_no == 2

Note, you can put the solution as an answer to you own question. This way its closed and valid.

Don't update your question to include an answer. If you would like to answer your own question, you can so as a separate answer below. It's up to the community to vote on answers.

May I ask where the "answer the post" button is? Would totally love to post solution from Andre as an answer and close the question. Thanks.

Someone marked it as duplicate and that closes it too.
